# MVC How to pass a model beetwen two different applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Here is the thing! At the company where I work there are two applications builted in MVC, one of these is used for loguin and some special funtionalities and the other one is used for global user's (I don't realy know why there are two applications. I think it most be just one).

Well, that is the context, now what I need to do is to pass a model from one application to the other, the problem is that I need to do it in the Action method to another Action method. The only method I found to do it is Redirect() but it only receive an url string and I can't pass query string's.

Is there a way to pass an encrypted model(I'm not sure if encrypted is the right word, but I think you know what I mean)?

Comment: You should use HttpClient or similar API's to make an Http call to the second application.

Comment: you can use ajax to send request to other application, in your ajax request you serialize your form and include it as data.